Unity ML-Agents not able to learn a seemingly simple task, feedback required on the training setup
I am training Ml-agents for my multiplayer racing game, but they aren't able to learn, despite trying over 10 different strategies to train them.
Game Description:
It is a multiplayer racing game, where you control cars (shaped like balls/marbles). The cars auto-accelerate and have a max speed. You only have two controls

Brake: Hold button to brake, and slow down car
Boost: Faster acceleration to a higher max speed. (Stays for 2 sec, then refreshes after 10 second)

The track have walls which contain the cars, but its possible to fall off track if you are too fast or hit a wall too hard. For example. Not Slowing down on turn. If you fall, you are respawned within 1s at the last checkpoint.
Track have densely packed checkpoints placed all over them, which are simple unity box colliders used as triggers
ML-Agents Setup:

Goal

Finish Track as fast as possible, and avoid falling of tracks

One episode is one lap around the track or max step of 2500, normally it should take less than 2000 steps to finish a lap



Actions:

Single Discrete Action Branch with a size of three, Brake, Boost, Do nothing

If you boost, car enters boost state and subsequent boost inputs means nothing until the boost refresh again. Car automatically exists boost state after 1.5 seconds, then boost refreshes in 10 second

Brake: As long as brake input is received, car stays in brake state, and leave, when the input changes. Brake input also cancels boost state



Rewards and Punishments:

-1 for falling of track

-0.5 for passing through a turn without falling

-0.01 for spam actions, like braking too much (brake within 0.2ms of previous brake). You should hold brake to slow down, rather than spam braking

-0.5 if you apply boost and cancel it with brake within 1 sec (to encourage boosting at proper sections of track)

-0.001 on each step, to encourage finishing track faster

0.1 * (normalized squared velocity) on passing through each checkpoint. (Faster the speed, more the reward)



Inputs

Normalized velocity

Boost cancel penalty active (means if agents cancels current boost state, it will be punished, since it just applied boost, less than 1 sec ago)

Spam Boost penalty active

Spam brake penalty active

Car State (Boost, Brake, or Running) (one hot encoded)

Incoming turn difficulty (Hard, Easy , Medium) (one hot encoded)

Incoming turn Direction (Left , Right) (one hot encoded)

Incoming turn distance (normalized between 0 and 1, if distance is less than 10, otherwise just 1)

Rays to judge position at track (distance from left and right walls of track)

Rays to see incoming turn (only three ray with 1 degree angle only)




Training Configs
behaviors:
  Race:
    trainer_type: ppo
    hyperparameters:
      batch_size: 512
      buffer_size: 102400
      learning_rate: 3.0e-4
      beta: 5.0e-4
      epsilon: 0.2
      lambd: 0.99
      num_epoch: 5
      learning_rate_schedule: linear
    network_settings:
      normalize: false
      hidden_units: 128
      num_layers: 2
    reward_signals:
      extrinsic:
        gamma: 0.99
        strength: 1.0
      gail:
        gamma: 0.99
        strength: 0.05
        demo_path: Assets/ML-Agents/Demos/LegoV7.demo
    behavioral_cloning:
      strength: 0.5
      demo_path: Assets/ML-Agents/Demos/LegoV7.demo
    max_steps: 4000000
    time_horizon: 64
    summary_freq: 50000
    threaded: true

ScreenShots


Problem
I have trained bots with tons of different configuration, with 1 or upto 50 stacked observations. Trained with and without demo (12000 steps for demo).
But my bots are not learning how to do a lap. They do not brake when a turn is coming, even though i have rewards and punishment setup for passing or falling off a turn. They also fail to learn the best places to boost, and would boost at very inconsistent locations, almost seems that they boost as soon as the boost is available.
I train bots on a very simple track first, for  2 million steps and then on a slightly more difficult track for 4 million steps.
I would absolute love if someone can offer me feedback on what am i doing wrong and how can i get the desired behavior. Its a simple enough task, yet I have been banging my head at it for a month now with barely any progress.

Id say your rewards arent big enough.. but im not a master..
